# mysql substring/left command isnt returning correct number of characters

Tags: mysql, bash, utf-8, wc, longtext

I'm executing the following statement:

```
select left(column,400) from table into outfile test;
```

I've also tried using substring function (with same results).

When I go to download the file and get a character count:

```
wc -c < test
```

I get 409 characters as a return.

Come someone assist me in why I'm getting an incorrect count?

The database table is set to utf8 and the column is longtext.

When I run the following it still doesn't give me correct length of characters:

```
select length(left(column, 400) from table where id in (1,2,3,4);
+-----------------------------+
| length(left(column,400))    |
+-----------------------------+
|                         402 |
|                         403 |
|                         412 |
|                         401 |
+-----------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `wc -c` is counting **bytes**, despite the character used for the switch.  With the DB in UTF-8, the mysql `left` is counting **characters**.  Since UTF-8 can use more than 1 byte per character, I expect the first 400 characters in `column` includes 8 characters that take 2 bytes (or less than 8 if some take 3 bytes).  There's probably a newline at the end as well.

Comment: Is there a mysql function that will work as I need? to only grab the specified number of characters?

Comment: You didn't understand what I said, `left` does grab the specified number of **characters**!  It's just that you tested that with `wc -c` which does not count **characters**!

Comment: I've updated my original posting to show the database still isn't returning the correct character count.

Comment: Once again you are confusing **characters** and **bytes**!  The mysql function `left` is counting characters, `length` is counting bytes.  In UTF-8 these can differ by a lot.

Comment: OK, I changed the length function to char_length function and got the results I was hoping for. Thanks.